# How to enable the www version of a GitHub Pages website

Tags: dns, web, github-pages, no-www, wwwroot

I have a website https://iamshouvikmitra.github.io but when I visit https://www.iamshouvikmitra.github.io it redirects me to a 404 page.
Is there any way I could also enable the www version of the website?

Comment: You are offtopic here, see instead in [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a www subdomain for the username.github.io web pages. If you'd like to use a www subdomain you can add a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).